# Cordova EmailComposer Options

Tags: iphone, cordova

Hi I am using the Cordova EmailComposer Plugin, with the following

```
Cordova.exec(null, null, "EmailComposer", "showEmailComposer", [args]);
```

What I am struggling with is setting subject line and information like that. When I change the `null` values it breaks the plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
// Define the arguments
var args = {
toRecipients : string,
ccRecipients : string,
bccRecipients : string,
subject : string,
body : string,
bIsHtml : boolean
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this sample code in the Body of your HTML page.

```
<body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                        <center><button onclick="cordova.exec(null, null, 'EmailComposer', 'showEmailComposer', [args]);">Compose Email</button></center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/EmailComposer.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
            var args = {
                toRecipients :["xyz@yahoo.co.in"],
                ccRecipients :["abc@gmail.com"],
                bccRecipients :["abc@gmail.com"],
                subject :"Hello",
                body : "HI",
                bIsHtml : true
            };

        </script>


    </body>
```